# Does the xamarin in the visual studio provide drag and drop in the xamarin.form?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Does the xamarin in the visual studio provide the drag and drop? When i am open a new project, and selecting the  cross platform > xamarin.form.portable and create it. There is 4 project opened, which is first portable project, ios, android and winphone project. However on the portable project, i add new interface which is cross platform > forms xaml page. After i create it, when i double click the xaml files, it does not lead me to the design view. it show the design code instead of design view. No matter how i right click and click open design view it is not working. Does the xamarin in the visual studio provide the drag and drop function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have any designer for xamarin forms in visual studio (and i think in xamarin IDE too)
Only for each specific plafforms when you are using Xamarin Core.

Comment: so that mean there is no sdk for the visual studio to open xamarin form in the vs?

Comment: As I know :( After a fast look in google i found this post in xamarin forum dated from 2014 https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19432/is-xamarin-forms-xaml-designer-supported-on-visual-studio